# How to replace brackets with quotation marks in titles

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am working on a paper using biblatex-chicago and I get the titles of both article and inbook entries framed in those brackets: «» . The journal requires doble inverted commas in both cases.

I couldn't find any similar question on the issue and I really don't have enough knowledge to set a solution out of biblatex documentation. I guess it has something to do with bibmacro and biblatex.def or biblatex.cfg but I can't understand what to do as I can't find any explanation for beginners.

I am a phylologist working in Spanish language with special characters for transcription.

This is my preamble with a short example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes15,short,backend=biber,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblioeg.bib}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the .bib info:

```
@Article{deMan,
  Title                    = {Autobiography as De-facement},
  Author                   = {Man, Paul de},
  Year                     = {1979},
  Number                   = {5},
  Pages                    = {919-930},
  Volume                   = {94},

  Journal                  = {MLN. Comparative Literature},
  Owner                    = {reinamora},
  Timestamp                = {2015.04.22}
}

@Inbook{Schipper,
  Title                    = {Two Andalusian poets on exile: Reflections on the poetry of Ibn `Amm\={a}r (1031-1086) and Moses ibn Ezra (1055-1138)},
  Author                   = {Schipper, Arie},
  Booktitle                = {The challenge of the Middle East},
  Year                     = {1982},
  Editor                   = {El-Shaykh, I. A. and others},
  Location                 = {Amsterdam},
  Pages                    = {113-121},
  Publisher                = {University of Amsterdam Institute for Modern Near Eastern Studies},

  Owner                    = {reinamora},
  Shorttitle               = {Two Andalusian poets on exile},
 Timestamp                = {2015.07.19}
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

If it is too simple for the users of this website, would you please recommend me a way to get help, as I have more questions and I cannot find any clear first steps. Like for example personal tutors for specific problems. I just want to learn and save time. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! So you don't want French quotes? Nor British quotes?

Comment: Use `\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}`, this will give you 66-99 (US-style) quotation marks when writing in Spanish.

Comment: Also please note that `utf8x` does not work to well with `biblatex`; `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is better in most use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked. I can't believe it was just that. I know there is incompatibilities with utf8x, but I need it becuase I am using special characters for Arabic transcription. All the best.

Comment: Mhh that might be one of the use cases where one is stuck with `utf8x`. Though I think one can probably convince `utf8` to work with that as well, but that will require work.

Comment: I don't mind working. But I need long explanations of basics all the time. If you have any advice to get started smoothly It would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to force "American"-style quotation marks in Spanish text you can simply use

```
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
```